# Concurrent Cache in Java

Tags: java, caching, concurrency

Suppose I have multiple threads accessing a map (actions are: inserting, retrieving, removing), and I'm using `ConcurrentHashMap`, do I need to do anything else or does ConcurrentHashMap 'covers' me?
Is there still something 'bad' that can happen?

Comment: Could you reformulate your question without such localized details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we do not know *all scenarios* of your task, according to what you have described, imho `ConcurrentHashMap` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into guava cache. Sounds very suited for your scenario.

[Link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)